# Inclusion and scope in Twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a template child.html.twig that extends parent.html.twig, within the child template, I included a partial _myVar.html.twig which contains a long logic that defines some specific variables.

I got the error : A template that extends another one cannot have a body, I don't understand because the included partial doesdn't output any content, it just defines variables and if its content is just written in child.html.twig the error disappear even outside all blocks.

I wished to put the included partial outside all blocks, but to fix the issue, I included it within one of the overriding blocks.

I got another problem of undefined variable, I don't know why the defined variables within the included partial are not available in the global scope after inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted your code, but normally you just have to take care of the following:

- the extends tag should be the first tag in the template
- every content in your extendig template has to be **defined in blocks** (those from the parent)